# I am looking for a specific word, need help please

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the apropriate word to describe someone who made this remark "As I said I don't know street ghetto talk". This is not racist as ghetto refers to a poor living area (to sum it up), and street talk is not racist either since that meaning is a way to describe slang speech from the poor city areas where people of all ethnic backgrounds have or currently live. It is how ever a word that i can not seem to remember or think of at this time. This person was being _______.  This person was grouping a bunch of individuals who have or currently do live where street slang is used as a way of speaking, and making it sound as if the person has not heard of the words, because the person is not from the ghetto areas.

Thank You for Helping.

Answer (score 1):

You might use

[Snobbish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snobbish) - being, characteristic of, or befitting a [snob](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snob) (one who tends to rebuff, avoid, or ignore those regarded as inferior)

or possibly

[Elitist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elitist) - a person who is or regards himself or herself as a member of a socially elite group